# Formally real non-Jordan algebras

Tags: ra.rings-and-algebras, jordan-algebras

Jordan, von Neumann and Wigner [1] showed that for any finite-dimensional real vector space $A$ with a bilinear commutative [power-associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_associativity) operation $\circ : A \times A \to A$, the **formal reality** condition

$$  a_1 \circ a_1 + \cdots + a_n \circ a_n = 0 \implies a_1, \dots, a_n = 0 $$

implies the remaining Jordan algebra axiom: for all $a \in A$, multiplication by $a \circ a$ commutes with multiplication by $a$.

Thus, in the definition of a [formally real Jordan algebra](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Jordan+algebra#OriginInQuantumPhysics) (which is the kind of Jordan algebra important in quantum mechanics), we can leave out the law $(a \circ a) \circ (a \circ b) = a \circ ((a \circ a) \circ b)$ without harm, since it follows from the other conditions... *in the finite-dimensional case*.

But their proof uses finite-dimensionality.  So, my question is:

**Do you know an example of an infinite-dimensional vector space with a commutative bilinear power-associative operation obeying the formal reality condition that is not a Jordan algebra?**

[1] P. Jordan, J. von Neumann and E. Wigner, On an algebraic generalization of the quantum mechanical formalism, *Ann. Math.* **35** (1934), 29-64.

Comment: I'd try the free commutative power-associative $\mathbf{R}$-algebra on 2 generators.

Comment: Nice question. +1 Still no answers.